# Given k sorted arrays, select one element from each array such that the difference of maximum and minimum element of the selected elements is minimum

Tags: data-structures

Given k sorted arrays, select one element from each array such that the difference of maximum element and minimum element of the selected elements is minimum. Example for k = 3

array1 : 1 13 27 30

array2 : 16 20 29

array3 : 2 3 14 18 19 22 25 28

ans: 2 
selected elements (27, 29, 28)

Answer (score 2):

Shortest range in k sorted arrays/lists is the standard problem you are looking for, [here is it's solution](https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/shortest-range-in-k-sorted-lists/).

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this answer : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-smallest-range-containing-elements-from-k-lists/ .
It's not contributed to me, I just found this on geeksforgeeks while searching for the same thing as you.