# Most Efficient Algorithm to Align an Multiple Ordered Sequences

Tags: arrays, algorithm, alignment, sequence

I have a strange feeling this is a very easy problem to solve but I'm not finding a good way of doing this without using brute force or dynamic programming. Here it goes:

> Given *N* arrays of ordered and monotonic values, find the set of positions for each array *i1*, *i2* *...* *in* that minimises pair-wise difference of values at those indexes between all arrays. In other words, find the positions for all arrays whose values are closest to each other. Multiple solutions may exist and arrays may or may not be equally sized.

> If A denotes the list of all arrays, the pair-wise difference is given by the sum of absolute differences between all values at the given indexes between all different arrays, as so:

[image]

An example, 3 arrays *a*, *b* and *c*:

```
a = [20 29 30 32 33]
b = [28 29 30 32 33]
c = [10 12 28 31 32 33]
```

The best alignment for this array would be `a[3] b[3] c[4]` or `a[4] b[4] c[5]`, because (32,32,32) and (33,33,33) are all equal values and have, therefore minimum pairwise difference between each other. (Assuming array index starts at 0)

This is a common problem in bioinformatics thats usually solved with `Dynamic Programming`, but due to the fact this is an ordered sequence, I think there's somehow a way of exploiting this notion of order. I first thought about doing this pairwise, but this does not guarantee the global optimum because the best local answer might not be the best global answer.

This is meant to be language agnostic, but I don't really mind an answer for a specific language, as long as there is no loss of generality. I know `Dynamic Programming` is an option here, but I have a feeling there's an easier way to do this?

Comment: Dynamic programming not needed. Just use multiple pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given k sorted arrays, select one element from each array such that the difference of maximum and minimum element of the selected elements is minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664066/given-k-sorted-arrays-select-one-element-from-each-array-such-that-the-differen)

Comment: Not exactly the same problem, If I understood it right. But the first link in that answer sorta tells me how to solve this problem. The differences here are that I want to know the indexes which minimize the pairwise difference, I don't care about the value of the range, I just want to know which indexes minimize the sum of pair-wise differences.

But https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/shortest-range-in-k-sorted-lists/ just showed me how to turn this into a sort of shortest path problem.

Comment: How to measure `minimases`?  For (27, 28, 29), the difference is 2 (sum of the difference between each **adjacent number**)?

Comment: What's a good running time? Would O((num arrays) * (num elements across all arrays)) be helpful?

Comment: @wonter I have made more explicit what I meant as minimization. But yes, it was exactly what you said. Let me know if its fully understandable now.

Comment: @Dave for now, any suggestion better than brute force would be good.

Comment: The simple solution with pointers would be O(N * M^2) where N is the number of elements in the arrays and M is the number of arrays, this is mainly because you calculate the distance pairwise, if you would only calculate the distance between min and max of selected values you could easily get it down to O(N * M)

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the number of arrays, the total number of elements across all arrays, the distribution of numbers (or deltas) within arrays? Is it at least safe to say that the total number of elements is much bigger than the number of arrays?

Comment: @maraca How do you plan on processing the elements so you're guaranteed to be considering the set which realizes the pairwise min at some point?

Comment: @Dave well yes, in practice there are more elements per array than the total amount of arrays. I read some of the links provided by Shridhar but the links for that answer don't make sense. For example the first link (https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/shortest-range-in-k-sorted-lists/) explores each position in a heap and stops whenever an array is depleted (which makes no sense, because the best possible alignment might be at the end.

Comment: @maraca the minimum between 2 values of the array is not guranteed to be the best global answer. Consider the example:
a = [2 4 5 7]
b = [2, 6, 10]
c = [6, 20]

The least different values in a and b is 2 but the overall closest values are (5,6,6) and (7,6,6). The introduction of a new array might change the entire solution.

Even if I have found the best answer yet, there might be a better answer ahead. This is starting to make me believe I can't really prune any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky thing is parsing the arrays so that at some point you're guaranteed to be considering the set of indices that realize the pairwise min. Using a min heap on the values doesn't work. Counterexample with 4 arrays: [0,5], [1,2], [2], [2]. We start with a d(0,1,2,2) = 7, optimal is d(0,2,2,2) = 6, but the min heap moves us from 7 to d(5,1,2,2) = 12, then d(5,2,2,2) = 9.

I believe (but haven't proved) that if we alway increment the index that improves pairwise distance the most (or degrades it the least), we're guaranteed to visit every local min and the global min.

Assuming n total elements across k arrays:

Simple approach: we repeatedly get the pairwise distance deltas (delta wrt. incrementing each index), increment the best one, and any time doing so switch us from improvement to degradation (i.e. a local minimum) we calculate the pairwise distance. All this is O(k^2) per increment for a total running time of O((n-k) * (k^2)).

With O(k^2) storage, we could keep an array where (i,j) stores the pairwise distance delta achieve by increment the index of array i wrt. array j. We also store the column sums. Then on incrementing an index we can update the appropriate row & column & column sums in O(k). This gives us a running time of O((n-k)*k)

Comment: " if we always increment the index that improves pairwise distance the most (or degrades it the least), we're guaranteed to visit every local min and the global min" That is absolutely correct, the arrays are all sorted and we start from the beginning of each array.

I like this approach but still, this approach will still need to expand every possible combination because how else would we know when to stop? Just because the deltas get bigger locally, they might decrease later on.

I am now almost sure this is an NP-Complete problem, but I'm still trying to prove it.

Comment: @AndréSantos This is O((num_elts)*(num_arrays)) unless there's an error I missed.

Comment: I don’t think its just that value. I believe now any algorithm must try every possible combination of indexes. I found out some bioinformatics papers which suggest Multiple Sequence Alignment is an NP-Complete problem.

Comment: @AndréSantos That's counter to your earlier comment that incrementing the index that improves pairwise distance the most will pass through the right answer. If that statement is true, you don't need to check all combinations of indices.

Comment: @AndréSantos We stop when we've incremented all the indices to the end, but since we're only ever incrementing that's O(sum of array lengths), not O(product of array lengths) combination of indices (with additional work per combo as outlined in my answer)

Comment: right, I'm sorry. I was **wrongly** assuming that by incrementing all counters, we woud be visiting every possible combination, but that, as you well said, is not necessarily the case. Thank you, this is likely the most efficient algorithm possible. Accepting as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

To just complete Dave's answer, here is the pseudocode of the delta algorithm:

```
initialise index_table to 0's where each row i denotes the index for the ith array
initialise delta_table with the corresponding cost of incrementing index of ith array and keeping the other indexes at their current values
cur_cost <- cost of current index table
best_cost <- cur_cost
best_solutions <- list with the current index table
while (can_at_least_one_index_increase)
    i <- index whose delta is lowest
    increment i-th entry of the index_table
    if cost(index_table) < cur_cost
        cur_cost = cost(index_table)
        best_solutions = {} U {index_table}
    if cost(index_table) = cur_cost
         best_solutions = best_solutions U {index_table}
    update delta_table
```

**Important Note**: During an iteration, some `index_table` entries might have already reached the maximum value for that array. Whenever updating the `delta_table`, it is necessary to never pick those values, otherwise this will result in a `Array Out of Bounds`,`Segmentation Fault` or undefined behaviour. A neat trick is to simply check which indexes are already at max and set a *sufficiently large* value, so they are never picked. If no index can increase anymore, the loop will end.

### Here's an implementation in Python:

```py
def align_ordered_sequences(arrays: list):
    def get_cost(index_table):
        n = len(arrays)
        if n == 1:
            return 0
        sum = 0
        for i in range(0, n-1):
            for j in range(i+1, n):
                v1 = arrays[i][index_table[i]]
                v2 = arrays[j][index_table[j]]
                sum += math.sqrt((v1 - v2) ** 2)
        return sum

    def compute_delta_table(index_table):
        # Initialise the delta table: we switch each index element to 1, call
        # the cost method and then revert the change, this avoids having to
        # create copies, which decreases performance unnecessarily
        delta_table = []
        for i in range(n):
            if index_table[i] + 1 >= len(arrays[i]):
                # Implementation detail: if the index is outside the bounds of
                # array i, choose a "large enough" number
                delta_table.append(999999999999999)
            else:
                index_table[i] = index_table[i] + 1
                delta_table.append(get_cost(index_table))
                index_table[i] = index_table[i] - 1
        return delta_table

    def can_at_least_one_index_increase(index_table):
        answer = False
        for i in range(len(arrays)):
            if index_table[i] < len(arrays[i]) - 1:
                answer = True
        return answer

    n = len(arrays)

    index_table = [0] * n
    delta_table = compute_delta_table(index_table)
    best_solutions = [index_table.copy()]
    cur_cost = get_cost(index_table)
    best_cost = cur_cost

    while can_at_least_one_index_increase(index_table):
        i = delta_table.index(min(delta_table))
        index_table[i] = index_table[i] + 1

        new_cost = get_cost(index_table)
        # A new best solution was found
        if new_cost < cur_cost:
            cur_cost = new_cost
            best_solutions = [index_table.copy()]
        # A new solution with the same cost was found
        elif new_cost == cur_cost:
            best_solutions.append(index_table.copy())
        # Update the delta table
        delta_table = compute_delta_table(index_table)

    return best_solutions
```

And here are some examples:

```py
>>> print(align_ordered_sequences([[0,5], [1,2], [2], [2]]))
[[0, 1, 0, 0]]

>> print(align_ordered_sequences([[3, 5, 8, 29, 40, 50], [1, 4, 14, 17, 29, 50]]))
[[3, 4], [5, 5]]
```

**Note 2:** this outputs indexes not the actual values of each array.