# Minimize the difference between maximum and minimum of the chosen elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose given m sorted array with the total number of n elements. our goal is, to choose one element from each sorted array such that the difference between the maximum and the minimum  of chosen elements is minimized.

I think we can solve the above problem in O(m log n) and I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664066/given-k-sorted-arrays-select-one-element-from-each-array-such-that-the-differen), but I can't use that reference to solve the above problem.

Comment: _"I can't use that reference to solve the above problem"_. Can you elaborate why? The answer mentioned in the linked post seems correct

Comment: Could you provide some *examples*, please?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur At the mentioned reference, use at least one element from each array, but in my problem, we use excatly one element from each array.

Comment: @Jut in the solution, they are using only one element from each array

Comment: I read those solutions, but the running time aren't (m log n).

Comment: Also, according to  the provided links to solution, the problem difinition say that: at least one element from each array.

Comment: The problem and solution are identical under “exactly one element from each array” and “at least one element from each array”.

Comment: @kcsquared how we can achieve the preferred running time?