# Minimize maximum difference in chosen elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

> Assume given `k` unsorted arrays such that total number of elements in
> arrays is n. We want to select exactly one element (let them be the
> set `A`) from each array. Our goal is to minimize difference between
> maximum and minimum in `A`.

I think it can't be done in `klogn` because at the worst case, we need read at least one time the input, so we can't do less than `n`. Also according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664066/given-k-sorted-arrays-select-one-element-from-each-array-such-that-the-differen) the running time of an algorithm when arrays are sorted is `nlogk`.  Are there an algorithm with running time `O(nk)` or `O(nlogk)`?

Comment: Unless i misunderstand the problem, you're really just interested in two elements. How about simply iterating on all elements and keeping the minimum and maximum?

Answer (score 0):

> I think it can't be done in O(k log n) because at the worst case, we need read at least one time the input, so we can't do less than O(n)

This is correct. For unsorted input arrays, we definitely can't do better than reading the entire input.

Let's assume the arrays are sorted. Then the following algorithm works:

1. Initialization:

   - Take the first elements from all k arrays and build a min heap
     consisting of them (with "tags" attached telling you which array they came from, and which index in this array they were at; in a language like C, this can be stored as a single pointer, assuming the arrays are (additionally) sentinel-terminated, or as a "slice" (pointer + remaining length)). This heap will be the "sliding" set of elements
     we consider.
   - Initialize a variable to hold the maximum of values in
     the heap.
   - Furthermore, initialize a variable to hold the best span encountered so far to be `max - min` (of the values in
     the heap).
   - Also initialize a variable that keeps track of the best set
     of elements encountered so far as a "copy" of the current heap.
2. Looping ("sliding"):

   1. Extract the minimum value from the heap. This will be the minimum of your range / span.
   2. The span is the maximum value of the heap (which we have conveniently kept track of in a variable) minus this minimum. If this candidate span is less than our current best span, update the current best span, and update the current best set of elements to be a copy of the elements in our heap.
   3. Now, update the heap. We took out an element corresponding to an array and an index in that array. Advance to the next index, where we find the next largest element. (If we've reached the end of the array, we're done: There are not enough elements to have a set of k distinct elements if we want to be larger than the current min left). In preparation of the next iteration, insert this element (+ tag) into the heap, and update the max value, if necessary, to restore the invariant that the heap consists of the k smallest elements from the k arrays not considered as minimum elements of a span yet.

In two places, I ask for a "copy" of the heap, to keep the current set of elements up to date (and safe from later mutation of the heap). This is suboptimal, performance-wise: It would incur costs O(k). Prima facie, this means we'd get an O(k) factor in every loop iteration, which we do not want.

[Persistent data structures to the rescue!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) A persistent data structure is one that does not mutate. Instead, when you update the data structure, you get an updated copy. This means that "copying" persistent data structures is O(1): You just need to copy a pointer, because what's behind this pointer is guaranteed to not change!

A persistent (min) heap can be implemented simply as a binary heap based on a persistent binary tree. Extracting the minimum is still O(log k): You just need to update the (up to two) paths in the binary tree (of depth log k) among which mutations happened. Inserting elements is analogeously O(log k).

This is seemingly not optimal. A Fibonacci heap can insert elements faster, in amortized O(1) time. But, since there will be about as many extractions as there will be insertions (assuming k < n), this does not make a difference: The runtime is dominated by the extractions, which would be O(log k) in a Fibonacci heap as well.

With pre-sorted input, we have the following runtimes:

- Initialization is O(k); note that a heap can be built in linear time. Note also that we can assume n > k (otherwise the problem is trivial) so this is O(n) as well.
- Each loop iteration is O(log k), being dominated by the extraction of an element from the heap, and the insertion of a new element, both of which are O(log k) operations. The other operations are constant time.
- There are at most O(n) loop iterations before you reach the end of an array.

All in all, we get the wanted runtime of O(n log k), but only for pre-sorted input.

Since your arrays are unsorted, you'll first have to sort them. That'll incur costs of O(n log n) - in the worst case, one array is very long (length almost n) while the others are small. So here we get O(n(log k + log n)) overall, not quite as good as O(n log k).

We could try to optimize by not fully sorting the arrays up-front, but instead turning each array into a min heap in linear time. Extracting elements from this min heap - which is the only thing our algorithm does: iterate the elements of each algorithm in ascending order - will still take time O(m) where m is the length of the respective array though, but it is possible that the algorithm terminates without fully considering an array (for example, because all values in this array are larger than all values in all other arrays, so you only need to look at the first few values).

However, this does not improve the worst case time complexity: If we consider a long array of length almost n and a smaller array with well interspersed values - including a value greater than the maximum in the long array - we will have to extract all values from the heap corresponding to the long array, thus again incurring the O(n log n) time complexity.